# I am using the LabelEncoder to label the categorical data in my data frame. I am getting this error. '(slice(None, None, None), 2)' is an invalid key

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a categorical data in I am trying to use LabelEncoder to encode the data to run regression model. However, I am getting this error.

'(slice(None, None, None), 2)' is an invalid key

I am trying to encode the 3rd column in my dataframe.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
df[:, 2] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df[:, 2])
```

Suppose the data in the 3rd column is as follows:

```
Col3
A
B
D
D
A
B
B
```

The expected result is:

```
Col3
1
2
3
3
1
2
2
```

Comment: `df.iloc[:, 2]` ? ---`df.iloc[:, 2] = labelencoder.fit_transform(df.iloc[:, 2])`

Comment: Thank you @Wen-Ben. Can you please post this as the answer so I can accept this answer? :)